# Why doest onEach is not working in Kotlin Flow for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

From Fragment, I'm calling one viewmodel fun and inside that I written this piece of code, but it's not printing anything! Only "Hello called" is printing.

Code:

```
 fun fetchUserReviewData1() {
    LogUtils.d("Hello called")
    flow {
        (1..5).forEach {
            LogUtils.d("Hello UserReviewViewModel1 it: " + it)
    //        delay(100) //delay the emission
            emit(it)
        }
    }.onEach { LogUtils.d("Hello UserReviewViewModel it: " + it) }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to [`collect`the flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flows-are-cold) somewhere?

Comment: @Michael Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not sure I'm new to the flow and basically converting existing architecture from suspend functions to flow in all places like repo n all.  Now sure wht's going wrong so just trying to solve with example code. please help what shd I do?

Comment: @IshikaSingh *from suspend functions to flow* - those are not equivalent. Suspend functions are for single-shot results, while flows are for streams of things. Make sure you're not switching from suspend functions to single-element flows, because that would be going the wrong way

Comment: @Joffrey Please tell me the solution for oneach and collect

Comment: @IshikaSingh there is already an answer telling you the solution: `onEach` is not `collect`. `onEach` is a non-terminal operator that just adds up to the cold flow. `collect` is a terminal operator that will actually trigger the flow collection. If you want to trigger the collection right here, use `collect` instead of `onEach`. It would be helpful to show the initial code you're trying to convert here, so we can help better with the actual use case

Comment: You will need to replace onEach with collect, and then figure out how you want to deal with that being a suspend function -- which you have to decide for yourself, since we don't know all the considerations for that decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that by default a Flow is **cold**. It means the code inside your `flow { ... }` directive and the following `onEach { ... }` won't be executed until a [collect](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html) is called on it.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but please modify my code. I understood that I have to collect the flow, but where I have to write onEach and where collect and onEach required after collect or not?

Comment: Modifying the code won't work as `collect` is a `suspending` function, your flow is not called from a suspending function. An alternative is launchIn but that requires a context argument.